# javax.ws.rs.RedirectionException: HTTP 302 Found in Talend 6.3.0

Tags: talend

I am facing below exception in Talend 6.3.0

```
Exception in component tRESTClient_1
javax.ws.rs.RedirectionException: HTTP 302 Found
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.convertToWebApplicationException(AbstractClient.java:504)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:897)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:865)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.invoke(WebClient.java:428)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.get(WebClient.java:611)
    at test_project.test_rest_0_1.Test_REST.tRESTClient_1Process(Test_REST.java:714)
    at test_project.test_rest_0_1.Test_REST.runJobInTOS(Test_REST.java:1111)
    at test_project.test_rest_0_1.Test_REST.main(Test_REST.java:968)
```

Please let me know solution to solve this issue

Comment: Can you share what `Test_REST.runJobInToS()` does?
without a code sample, the only thing I can say is that HTTP 302 means http redirect.  Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302)

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 302 is a redirect, could be because of the  certificate problem. 
First you can try adding a / or remove from end point of URL.